# findById with Quarkus, Mongodb and Panache raises the error: "This method is normally automatically overridden in subclasses"

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

I began with the Quarkus tutorial: https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb-panache for learning how to use Mongo in Quarkus, but although my entities are storing right on the database when I try to use `findByIdOptional` from `PanacheMongoRepository` the console displays this error:

```java
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This method is normally automatically overridden in subclasses
    at io.quarkus.mongodb.panache.runtime.MongoOperations.implementationInjectionMissing(MongoOperations.java:633)
    at io.quarkus.mongodb.panache.PanacheMongoRepositoryBase.findByIdOptional(PanacheMongoRepositoryBase.java:102)
    at com.basketmaster.backend.common.infraestructure.CrudMongoRepository.findById(CrudMongoRepository.kt:25)
```

```kotlin
interface CrudRepository<M : Model<*>> {
    fun save(model: M): M
    fun findById(id: String): M
}

@ApplicationScoped
class CrudMongoRepository<M : Model<*>> : CrudRepository<M>, PanacheMongoRepository<M> {

    override fun save(model: M): M {
        persistOrUpdate(model)
        return model
    }

    override fun findById(id: String): M {
        val optional = super.findByIdOptional(ObjectId(id))
        return optional.orElseThrow { NotFoundException() }
    }

}
```

I noticed the interface PanacheMongoRepository inherit from PanacheMongoRepositoryBase but findByIdOptional is not implemented:

```kotin
public interface PanacheMongoRepositoryBase<Entity, Id> {
    // ...
    @GenerateBridge(targetReturnTypeErased = true)
    default Entity findById(Id id) {
        throw INSTANCE.implementationInjectionMissing();
    }
    @GenerateBridge
    default Optional<Entity> findByIdOptional(Id id) {
        throw INSTANCE.implementationInjectionMissing();
    }
}
```

How should I use Panache for finding the entities by id? I don't understand why these methods are unimplemented but the tutorial uses them and it works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods of MongoDB with Panache entities/repositories are implemented at build time via bytecode generation.

For this to happens, you need to have an entity /  a reposotiry with a concrete parameter type not a generic one as the extension needs to know the concrete type at build time to be able to use the right parameterized MongoDB Collection.

So here, the issue is that you cannot directly use your `CrudMongoRepository`, you need to subclass it and provide a concrete parameter type.